# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error in Frgament

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

```
public class FragmentSurf extends Fragment
{
    private View v;
    private final String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.1.40/api/web/products/surf";
    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewProdutos;
    private List<Produtos> listaProdutos;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.surf_fragment, container, false);
        listaProdutos = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerViewProdutos = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.shop_recSurfProdutos);
        jsonRequest();
        return v;
    }

    public void jsonRequest(){

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                    try{
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Produtos produtos = new Produtos();
                        produtos.setNomeProduto(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        produtos.setPrecoProduto(jsonObject.getInt("price"));
                                              ...
                        listaProdutos.add(produtos);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                setUpRecyclerView(listaProdutos);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

            }
        });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(List<Produtos> listaProdutos){
        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), listaProdutos);
        recyclerViewProdutos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerViewProdutos.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Can you find what's wrong to appear that error?**

> Can it be on the setUpRecyclerView? Most on the answers back on other posts weren't to clarifying...
>   private void setUpRecyclerView(List listaProdutos){
>               RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), listaProdutos);
>               recyclerViewProdutos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
>               recyclerViewProdutos.setAdapter(myAdapter);
>           }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to set adapter from onResponse and you haven't set adapter in creation phase before.
Try to add calling of setUpRecyclerView() in onCreateView() before calling of jsonRequest()

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.surf_fragment, container, false);
listaProdutos = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerViewProdutos = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.shop_recSurfProdutos);
setUpRecyclerView(listaProdutos)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to wait for your Json request to complete in order to set up the RecyclerView.

The RecyclerView can be set up, i.e. the adapter and layout manager can be assigned, with empty data in `onCreateView()`.

Thereafter the data can be updated on the adapter and then it can be asked to update/refresh using `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

It's a very standard way of initialising and updating a RecyclerView in Android. Please look up the documentation of the method and things should be clear to you. Else, let me know and I can post some code snippet for you.